# How to fix terminal when it gets "damaged", swallowing newlines

Tags: terminal

Sometimes when I use bash, when everything is going right
I get prompts like this:

```
user@name$
user@name$
user@name$
```

For some reason, I do not know, sometimes my terminal gets "damaged" and I get this:

```
user@name$ user@name$ user@name$ user@name$
```

and everything I write is hidden. So I had to shut down this terminal tab and open a new one. How do I fix that?

Comment: `How I fix that` usually, type `reset` + enter

Comment: Missing information include: What is the terminal application? What have you tried that did not work? Is it a remote terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually not a shell-related problem. Did you `cat` a binary file by accident?
Assuming you are on Linux or another Unix-like system, try

```
stty sane
```

to set sane terminal settings again. The stty(1) manual page makes for interesting reading. :-)

Comment: Thank you that's super helpful for me. this problem always happened because my workflow with Vim depends on moving Vim to background and foreground all the time.
I use Ctrl+z and Ctrl+f (f==forground) please see this [demo](https://youtu.be/zvmCi2i___w) my [bashrc](https://github.com/smalinux/dotfiles/blob/master/.bashrc#L195) this answer works smooth with me. but my workflow will be perfect if I could invoke `stty sane` after every time I move any app to background.

Comment: @smalinux Vim puts the terminal in *raw mode* and Ctrl-Z does not undo this. Why not start a shell from within vim, e.g. `:!bash -l`? Use Ctrl-D when done (or exit).

Comment: yah )) do you know I don't think 'not sure' that this is not the case with OS like FreeBSD, Vim can't put the terminal in raw mode...